# Pre-filling Multiple Forms and submitting on one view with multiple controller functions cakephp

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, view, controller

I am building an application with cakePHP (I am new to coding in general), I want to have multiple forms on one view (edit.ctp) with forms that use separate controller functions. I have looked around and am not sure how to accomplish this since one controller function is pretty much tied to the view file with the same name as the controller method. Here are my controller methods:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
    }
    if(!$user) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
    }
    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
public function editProfile($id = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
    }
    if(!$user) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your profile has been editted.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Your profile could not be editted. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    $this->view = ('edit');
}
public function changePassword()
{
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
    }
    $password = $this->Users->get($id);
    if(!$password) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        if ( password_verify($this->request->data('old_password'), $password->password) === true && password_verify($this->request->data('password'), $password->password) === false ) {
            $password = $this->Users->patchEntity($password, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($password)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your profile has been editted.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Your profile could not be editted. Please, try again.'));
        } elseif ( password_verify($this->request->data('old_password'), $password->password) === false ) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Your old password is not correct.'));
        } elseif ( password_verify($this->request->data('old_password'), $password->password) === true ) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('You must enter a password different from your current one.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Your profile could not be editted. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('password'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['password']);
    $this->view = ('edit');
}
```

Here is my view:

```
//users/edit.ctp
<div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Edit Your Profile</h1>
        <?= $this->Form->create(null, array('url'=>array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'editProfile'))) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('full_name', ['value' => $user->full_name]) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('email', ['value' => $user->email]) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Save')) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

        <?= $this->Form->create(null, array('url'=>array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'changePassword'))) ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Change Your Password</legend>
            <?= $this->Form->input('old_password', ['type' => 'password', 'value' => '']) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password', ['label' => 'New Password', 'type' => 'password', 'value' => '']) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password_confirmation', ['label' => 'New Password Confirmation', 'type' => 'password', 'value' => '']) ?>
        </fieldset> 
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Change Password')) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
        <p><?= $this->Html->link('Back', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index']); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The main issue is that the $user/$password variables do not get submitted to the edit.ctp view from the editProfile and changePassword methods so it throws an error of undefined variable, so I tried to set it in the edit function and it gets rid of the error but then I cannot get the information to save. The other methods are not getting the id of the submitted data (Record not found in table "users" with primary key [NULL])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured out a quick fix by changing the controller function changePassword variable $password to $user and then instead of placing null inside $this->Form->create I put $user in both forms and because they are submitting to two different functions in the controller it still worked.

Comment: almost all Form helper''s functionality is configurable. the create method takes many useful options , **url** to submit to being one. also you can set it post to diff action and controller.